# Aws ses email sender working in local but when deployed its not working in tomcat

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, tomcat, deployment, amazon-ses

I have a code for sending email using amazon ses .It worked in local. When i deployed in tomcat, didnt even deploy it got some error like this :

"Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'cachingConfigurer' parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'java.util.List<org.springframework.cloud.aws.cache.CacheFactory>' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}"

Think it is because of spring-cloud-starter-aws dependency . and this dependency is getting imported in a file for "SimpleEmailServiceJavaMailSender".
can we send email without this "SimpleEmailServiceJavaMailSender" .Any other code to send email with aws ses ..

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in learning how to send email via the Amazon Simple Email Service within a Spring BOOT app, then use the SES Java V2 API. Here is a multi service AWS tutorial that creates a Spring BOOT app that sends email messages using SES (among other tasks such as pulling data from an Amazon DynamoDB table).

[Creating the DynamoDB web application item tracker](https://github.com/awsdocs/aws-doc-sdk-examples/tree/master/javav2/usecases/creating_dynamodb_web_app)

This app emails a MS Excel doc as an example of how to email an attachment by using the SES.

I suspect you are not using the AWS Java V2 API, which is strongly recommended by Amazon:

.
**The AWS SDK for Java 2.x is a major rewrite of the version 1.x code base. It’s built on top of Java 8+ and adds several frequently requested features. These include support for non-blocking I/O and the ability to plug in a different HTTP implementation at run time.**